# Building a project for windows iot - raspberry

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi

I have windows 10 (64 bit) and Qt 5.7 (32 bit) and Visual Studio 2015 on my computer.I installed UWP arm7(MSVC2015), UWP X86(MSVC2015) and UWP X64(MSVC2015) from Qt 5.9 via Qt online installer.I want to develop this application for the raspberry pi 3 with windows 10 iot core.
But I have this error: qt.winrtrunner: Using the Appx profile. Deployment operation did not succeed.